# Curl grab HTML content

Tags: php, curl

I have a webpage which requires a login.

I am using curl to build the HTTP authentication request. It works, but I am not able to grab all the content from my links. I miss all the images.

How can I grab the images as well?

```
<?php

// create cURL resource
$URL = "http://10.123.22.38/nagios/nagvis/nagvis/index.php?map=Nagvis_CC";
//Initl curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set HTTP authentication option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);  // Load in the destination URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); //Normal HTTP request, not SSL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "guest:test" ); // Pass the user name and password

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$content = curl_exec($ch);

$result = curl_getinfo($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

echo $content;
echo $result;

?>
```

I'm getting this warning message `Warning: curl_error(): 2 is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\LiveServices\LoginTest.php on line 24`

Answer (score 2):

cURL doesn't get images or any other 'content', it just gets the raw HTML page. Are you saying you are missing `<img />` tags that are present on the original page?

cURL also doesn't parse any CSS or JavaScript, so if the content is modified with those, it won't come through. For example, you may be unable to get a `background-image` of an element unless you do more scraping, that is, get the associated CSS file and parse that.

Comment: Also, it's not nearly as elegant, but you could also shell out to `wget` which could grab the images and everything for you. curl, from code, is going to me more reliable though.

Comment: Hi,

Do you have an example to do shell out wget in my situation? Grab all the contents

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I have is that I cannot see the html, so I cannot be sure what the problem is. Having said that, two things occur to me.

The first thing to check is if the images are relative or not. If they are displayed in the form `../xyz/foo.jpg` or `foo.jpg` then you will either need to edit the images src to the full url **or** add the [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) to the html

For parsing HTML, use the [Simple HTML DOM library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) as it is faster than rolling your own.

The second issue may be that the images also require the user to be logged in. If this is the case you would also have to download all the images, and either embed them in the content after base 64 encoding them, or store them temporally on your server.

Comment: Hi Yacoby, 

I can send the HTML to u. can u pls provide me ur email address? 

Regards,
Qing

Answer (score -1):

Here the some html codes:
The images that I want to get:

```
<img id="backgroundImage" style="z-index: 0;" src="/nagios/nagvis/nagvis/images/maps/Nagvis_CC.png"/>

<a href="/nagios/cgi-bin/extinfo.cgi?type=2&host=business_processes&service=NLThirdPartyLive" target="_self">
```

And a lot of javascript.

I tried to use simple HTML dom libray, but the output is array. nothing

```
require("/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");
```

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'WhateverBrowser1.45');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://10.123.22.38/nagios/nagvis/nagvis/index.php?map=Nagvis_CC');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); //Normal HTTP request, not SSL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "guest:test" ); // Pass the user name and password
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$html= str_get_html($result);
echo $ret= $html->find('table[class=header_table]');

echo $result;